# GSAP Flip with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gsap

I try to get the basic GSAP Flip example to work with webpack, but i get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: pi is not a function
> at new t at main.js
> at es at main.js
> at t.getState at main.js
> at HTMLDocument.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="FlipContainer">
    <div class="FlipSquare" id="sq1">1</div>
    <div class="FlipSquare" id="sq2">2</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
import  gsap  from 'gsap';
import  {Flip}  from 'gsap/all';

gsap.registerPlugin(Flip);

console.log(Flip);

const squares = gsap.utils.toArray(".FlipSquare");

function doFlip() {
  // Get the initial state
  const state = Flip.getState(squares);
  
  // Make DOM or styling changes (swap the squares in our case)
  swap(squares);
  
  // Animate from the initial state to the end state
  Flip.from(state, {duration: 2, ease: "power1.inOut"});
}

// Given an Array of two siblings, append the one that's first so it's last (swap)
function swap([a, b]) {
  a.parentNode.children[0] === a ? a.parentNode.appendChild(a) : a.parentNode.appendChild(b);
}

// click anywhere to flip
document.addEventListener("click", doFlip);
```

**webpack.config**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'main.css'
    })],
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './Javascript/Modules/global.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Javascript'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Css'),
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        static: 'dist',
        watchContentBase: true
    },
};
```

The log is displaying:

> ƒ t(){}

I installed gsap with

```
npm install gsap
```

I tried to import Flip in other ways but nothing changed.
Happy for every help, thanks!

Comment: Show the webpack config and the full error stack.